# Aligning equations when the number of columns change

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, amsthm

I want to have some equations aligned in two columns followed by a single centered equation, i.e. something that looks like multiple `align` enviroments, one after another, but with no excessive space between them. Ideally, there would be an `align`-like environment where the number of columns may be different in different rows, but all rows that have the same number of columns would be horizontally aligned together.

Also, in the last equation I have `cases` and it doesn't work well with `proof`. I have found no place to put `\qedhere` that produces the result I want – the qed symbol on the righthand end, but with no extra line.

Finally, I'd appretiate any general advice how to treat issues like this – I'm writing some math, I want to do something natural that is a slight generalization of what I do in TeX regularly, but it is a big problem to explain this to TeX. It feels like (La)TeX doesn't work on the level of abstraction I desire, and issues like this interrupt my work.

An example follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        We have the following equalities.
        \begin{align*}
            f^\leftrightarrow(x) &= f(-x) & f^{\mathrel{\text{\ooalign{$\swarrow$\cr$\nearrow$}}}}(x) &= -f(-x) \\
            f^+(x) &= \max(f, 0) & f^-(x) &= \min(f, 0) \\
            |x| = \begin{cases}
                +x \quad \text{if $x \ge 0$} \\
                -x \quad \text{if $x \le 0$} \\
            \end{cases} % \qedhere
        \end{align*} \qedhere
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `gather*`, and nest an `aligned` enviroinment within it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

    \begin{proof}
        We have the following equalities.
        \begin{gather*}
            \begin{aligned}
            f^\leftrightarrow(x) &= f(-x) & f^{\mathrel{\text{\ooalign{$\swarrow$\cr$\nearrow$}}}}(x) &= -f(-x) \\
            f^+(x) &= \max(f, 0) & f^-(x) &= \min(f, 0) \\
            \end{aligned}\\
            |x| = \begin{cases}
                +x \quad \text{if $x \ge 0$} \\
                -x \quad \text{if $x \le 0$}
            \end{cases}
            \qedhere%
        \end{gather*}
    \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `ntheorem` you can have a better alignment of the end-of-proof symbol, as it allows the local replacement of a symbol with another symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{$\square$}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\qedsymbol{\bllap[1.75ex]{$\square$}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{proof}%
        We have the following equalities.
        \qed%
        \begin{gather*}
            \begin{alignedat}{3}
            f^\leftrightarrow(x) &= f(-x) & f^{\mathrel{\text{\ooalign{$\swarrow$\cr$\nearrow$}}}}(x) &= -f(-x) \\
            f^+(x) &= \max(f, 0) &\hspace{6em} f^-(x) &= \min(f, 0) \\
            \end{alignedat}\\
           |x| = \begin{cases}
                +x \quad \text{if $x \ge 0$} \\
                -x \quad \text{if $x \le 0$}
            \end{cases}
        \end{gather*}
    \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, that is one think I have tried. The problem is that the space between the columns is now smaller in original `align*`.

Comment: You can use `alignedat` to have full control on the spacing of the columns. You can see the result in another code, based on  `ntheorem`, that I've just added to show how to have a nicer placement of the end-of-proof symbol (on the same line as the last line of the  `cases` environment).

Comment: Thank you. Where did the magic constant `1.75ex` came from? Do you share my frustration that we need so many modifications in the source to get the desired behavior?

Comment: The value was found by trial and error. The `\bllap` command, from `stackengine` is a combination of `llap` ,  `\smash`  and `stackunder`. It could be automatic if I knew how to measure the height of the `cases` environment. As this problem is rather exceptional, I think (all equations do not end up in a cases environment…), I'm not sure it's worth to delve into it – and personally, I don't know how to do it.